# Make top row of GridView non-scrollable

Tags: java, android

I have a GridView of 9 rows of which the first one is sort of "header" row.

As there are 8 more rows they flow beyond the end of screen and need to be scrolled down to.
However this scrolling also causes the first row to go "off-screen".

Was wondering if there is any way I can prevent the first row alone from being scrolled off?

I dont want to make this a separate LinearLayout as it is part of a dynamic View (the GridView) that I create at runtime.

TIA

Comment: If we use a TableLayout instead is there some way of guaranteeing that the header row would always show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Was wondering if there is any way I
>   can prevent the first row alone from
>   being scrolled off?

Not that I am aware of, sorry.

Comment: Guess then we need to have this in a separate layout?

Comment: @source.rar: Yes. Also, with respect to your `TableLayout` comment, either the whole thing won't scroll, or the whole thing will scroll (if you put it in a `ScrollView`). I am not aware of anything in Android that has the notion of a single widget being partially scrollable.